# How far can an $N$-fermion wavefunction be from the nearest Slater determinant?

Tags: functional-analysis, optimization, hilbert-spaces, mathematical-physics, grassmannian

Consider a system of $N$ non-relativistic spin-$0$ fermions in $D$-dimensional space, all of the same species. The wavefunction of such a system can be represented by a function $\psi(\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_N)$, where each boldface argument is a point in $D$-dimensional space, and the function is antisymmetric with respect to permutations of those $N$ points. The inner product is the usual one:
$$
\newcommand{\la}{\langle}
\newcommand{\ra}{\rangle}
 \la \psi|\phi\ra 
 \equiv \int_{\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_N}
   \psi^*(\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_N)
  \phi(\mathbf{x}_1,...,\mathbf{x}_N).
$$
Let $S$ be the set of non-zero wavefunctions of the form
$$
 \sum_\pi (-1)^\pi\prod_{k=1}^N \psi_k(\mathbf{x}_{\pi(k)})
$$
where the sum is over permutations of the $N$ arguments. Such a wavefunction is sometimes called a Slater determinant.

For $N\geq 2$, does the quantity
$$
\max_{|s\ra\in S}
\frac{\la \psi|s\ra\,\la s|\psi\ra}{\la \psi|\psi\ra\,\la s|s\ra}
\tag{1}
$$
have a non-zero minimum value among all non-zero vectors $|\psi\ra$ in the Hilbert space? If so, what is that minimum value as a function of $N$ and $D$?

Comment: I believe there is no minimum, at least for $N=2$. I don't have time to write a full answer right now, but here is the rough idea: without loss of generality we can assume that all wavefunctions are normalized. Restrict to $D=1$ for simplicity, define $u=(x_1+x_2)/\sqrt2, v=(x_1-x_2)/\sqrt2$ and consider the wavefunction $\sqrt{2\pi/\varepsilon}\: v\: e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}(v^2/\varepsilon+u^2\varepsilon)}$ for $\varepsilon>0$. We can check that it is antisymmetric, it has unit norm and as $\varepsilon \to 0$ it tends to something proportional to $\varepsilon \: \delta'_{2\varepsilon}(v)$.

Comment: (continued) Here $\delta_{2\varepsilon}$ is a [nascent delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function). The inner product of this function with any wavefunction of the form $f(x_1)g(x_2)-f(x_2)g(x_1)$, after performing the integration on $x_2$, reduces to $K \varepsilon \int (f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)) dx + O(\varepsilon^2)$, for some unimportant constant $K$. This can be made as small as we want by decreasing $\varepsilon$.

Comment: @pregunton Thank you! That answers my question, and I can see how it works intuitively (the case $D=1,N=2$ can actually be visualized). If you'd like to copy your comments into an answer, I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no minimum, at least for $N=2$.

Without loss of generality, we can assume that all wavefunctions in the problem have norm $1$.

Restricting to $D=1$, we perform the change of coordinates $u=(x_1+x_2)/\sqrt2,\quad v=(x_1-x_2)/\sqrt2$ and consider the wavefunction

$$\psi(u,v)=\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{\varepsilon}} v\: e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}(v^2/\varepsilon+u^2\varepsilon)}$$

for $\varepsilon>0$. This function is even in $u$ and odd in $v$, so it is antisymmetric in the original coordinates. The integral of its square over all space is

$$\iint \psi(u,v)\:du\:dv= \iint \frac{2\pi}{\varepsilon} v\: e^{-\pi(v^2/\varepsilon+u^2\varepsilon)} = \frac{2\pi}{\varepsilon} \frac{\varepsilon^{3/2}}{2\pi}\varepsilon^{-1/2}=1.$$

On the other hand, we have

$$\psi(u,v)= -2 \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}\varepsilon\: e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}u^2\varepsilon}\:\frac{d}{dv} \left( \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\varepsilon}} e^{-\frac{\pi}{2}v^2/\varepsilon}\right).$$

As $\varepsilon\to 0$, he term inside the derivative is a [nascent delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#Representations_of_the_delta_function), while the exponential term outside is $1+O(\varepsilon)$.

Now we return to the original coordinates, and consider any (normalized) wavefunction of the form

$$s(x_1,x_2)=f(x_1)g(x_2)-f(x_2)g(x_1),$$

as in the problem. The inner product $\langle s | \psi \rangle$ can be computed by using the properties of the Dirac delta derivative to perform the integration on $x_2$. The result is

$$K \varepsilon \int (f'(x)g(x)-f(x)g'(x)) \:dx + O(\varepsilon^2),$$

for some unimportant constant $K$. This can be made as small as we want by decreasing $\varepsilon$.

If I'm not mistaken, this can be generalized to $D>1$ by taking $\psi$ to be the product of the former function in the first pair of coordinates by nascent Dirac deltas in the other coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Curiously I am working on this subject in my research in Theoretical Chemistry. An analytical expression to this is unknown, except for $N=2$ (see [10.1103/PhysRevA.64.022303](https://arxiv.org/abs/quant-ph/0012094) or [10.1103/PhysRevA.89.012504](https://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1848v1)). For the general case an analytical expression is unlikely to be possible, and an optimisation over S is required, such as discussed in 10.1103/PhysRevA.89.012504 (although they consider a more general set $S$, you question is a particular case). The set you named as $S$ is actually close related to the Grassmannian (as you probably know, considering the tags you added): If you consider the equivalence classes upon the relation $\psi \sim \lambda \psi$, $\lambda$ a non zero scalar you have an manifold isomorphic to the Grassmannian.

When (hopefully soon) my research on this subject gets published, I will be happy to share it here.

Comment: Thank you for the reply and for the references! Can you point me to where in those papers the $N=2$ result is given? I looked through the arXiv versions and saw some related results but didn't find a non-trivial bound on my expression (1).

Comment: So, you are right in complaining concerning the first reference, they actually show that the correlation measure that they introduce (what you want can also be viewed as a correlation measure) can be evaluated analytically for two particle systems. I guess (no more than a guess, I didn't run the math) that what they do can be related to what you want, but it is definitively not direct.

Comment: Concerning the second reference: they show in section II.B that for the two-particle case the Slater determinant (the element of $S$) you are looking for is the one formed by the natural orbitals (the orbitals that diagonalise the one-particle density matrix).

Comment: Hmm, I have been reading carefully what you want, and I see now that you have a non-fixed $|\psi\rangle$. Ok, sorry, I misunderstood, so my answer does not answer you.So, you want the max$_{all \psi}$ (min$_{s \in S}$). Ok. This is obviously not zero, since every non zero (and say, normalised to unit) $\psi$ can be written as linear combination of elements of $S$. And now, the minimum value of this must be for $\psi$ that is as distant as possible to $S$, or in other words a maximally correlated $\psi$.

Comment: Right -- It's a question about how much the set of Slater determinants "fills up" the Hilbert space. Still, thank you for posting this. The work you cited / will cite is closely related, and sometimes thinking about related things can inspire new approaches to the original question.